# Reading YAML in Java without boiler plate

Tags: java, yaml

I was wondering if there is a way to read a YAML file in Java without having to create a lot of POJO's but still have the ability to cleanly read the elements of the YAML. Meaning, not messing with LinkedHashmaps.
Is there a library or something that can do this?

Thanks in advance
Regards

Comment: What's wrong with POJOs?

Comment: What do you expect to happen? How do you expect your code to be structured? Either you have something maplike - with `String` keys or the code must be preset at _compile time_. If the latter how do you automate the code generation? A random YAML could have _any_ structure. Do you have a schema?

Comment: with SnakeYaml you could read it into a Map<String, Object>, or a Pojo.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jackson library, the ObjectMapper (the most important class of that library) has a method readTree which returns a JsonNode, which you can read and traverse. Usage is pretty simple:

```
String yamlString = 
        "---\n" +
        "name: Bob\n" +
        "age: 35";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
JsonNode root = mapper.readTree(yamlString);
String name = root.get("name").asText();
int age = root.get("age").asInt();
```

Make sure you check some tutorials and don't get confused if you find too much stuff about JSON, because Jackson has been originally a library parsing JSON, other formats were added later.

Comment: Ah sorry, you wanted YAML, not JSON, let me fix that.